# cfselect problem

Tags: select, coldfusion, auto-populating

I theory  seems to be the answer to the pre populated selectbox issue.

```
<cfselect name = "regions" query = "getRegions" selected="10" value="id" display="name" ></cfselect>
```

this is what it outouts

```
<option value="8">Dumfries & Galloway</option>
<option value="9">Dundee City</option>
<option value="10" selected="selected">East Ayrshire</option>
<option value="11">East Dunbartonshire</option>
```

but my option 10 is not selected automatically. The html looks ok any reason why?

Thanks,

R.

Comment: Just and idea: are you using Firefox? If you do F5 it keeps previously selected option active. Making page reload through address bar should reset the form.

Comment: Or use CTRL-F5 for a hard refresh!

Comment: Sergii, you should make that an answer so it can be chosen as the solution.

Comment: I would avoid CFSELECT... You're better off doing it w/o it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox then that is probably the reason, because it keeps form values persistent across page reloads. You can use a different browser, or add something to the query string like `?abc=123`.